# How to Create a Ticket That Belongs To a Process OTRS 5 - REST

Tags: rest, otrs

**Context**

I'm developing a custom service in a .Net MVC Web Application that will connect to an OTRS web service to create/list/update tickets.
We are implementing many process workflows to make things works more efficiently.

**Problem**

I cannot find a way to "attach" a new ticket to a process, I know how to create a normal ticket, but not a process ticket.
I found a [perl script](http://doc.otrs.com/doc/api/otrs/5.0/Perl/Kernel/System/ProcessManagement/Process.pm.html) that seems to do what I need to, but I cannot find a way to connect the problem with the solution.

**Perl Script**

```
ProcessTicketProcessSet()
    Set Ticket's ProcessEntityID

    my $Success = $ProcessObject->ProcessTicketProcessSet(
        ProcessEntityID => 'P1',
        TicketID        => 123,
        UserID          => 123,
    );

    Returns:
    $Success = 1; # undef
    1 if setting the Activity was executed
    undef if setting failed
```

**Normal Ticket**

- URL:

`http://someDomain.com.br/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/SomeWebServiceName/Ticket?UserLogin=user&Password=abcd`

- Method: POST
- Body:

  `{
      "UserLogin": "user",
      "Password": "abcd",
      "Ticket": {
          "Title": "REST - To Create Ticket",
          "Type": "Unclassified",
          "QueueID": "5",
          "State": "new",
          "Priority": "3 normal",
          "CustomerUser": "someuser@someemail.com.br"
      },
      "DynamicField": [{
              "Name": "CustomFieldOne",
              "Value": "value1"
          },
          {
              "Name": "CustomFieldTwo",
              "Value": "value2"
          }

      ],
      "Article": {
          "Subject": "Rest - Article Ticket",
          "Body": "Test Article Creation",
          "ContentType": "text/plain; charset=utf8"
      }
  }`

How can I create a ticket that belongs to a process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a ticket which belongs to a process you need to set two dynamic fields of a ticket.

- ProcessManagementProcessID (which is representing the process)
- ProcessManagementActivityID (which is representing the activity step of the process)

In case you also can set both dynamic fields later to set the process.

In case you do not know what values you need to set, just launch a process ticket via the UI and check via the ticket histories what values are set for both dynamic fields.